# evaluate jsonpath expression for the example

Tags: json, jsonpath, json-path-expression, json-extract, json-arrayagg

```
{
  "a": [
    {
      "b": {
        "c": [
          {
            "id": "123"
          }
        ],
        "d": {
          "e": {
            "f": [
              {
                "name": "abc",
                "type": "in"
              },
              {
                "name": "xyz",
                "type": "out"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "b": {
        "c": [
          {
            "id": "456"
          }
        ],
        "d": {
          "e": {
            "f": [
              {
                "name": "def",
                "type": "out"
              },
              {
                "name": "pqr",
                "type": "out"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to extract the id's for which type='in'. So, as per the above example , the output should be 123 as only abc in the first element has the type 'in'.
I tried multiple ways but not succeeded to extract it. Can someone please help on this?

With the following expression I am able to extract the node whose value is 'in' but how to extract the corresponding id/id's of the same object (i.e. 123)?

```
$.a[*].b.d[*].f[?(@.type=='in')]
```

Can try the json path here :
[JSON path online tool](https://jsonpath.com/)

UPDATE :

As per the suggestion from gregsdennis , I tried with the following by converting the IETF Json path mentioned to equivalent Jayway Json path which is not working :

```
$.a[?(@.b.d.e.f[?(@.type=='in')])].b.c[*].id
```

syntax error : jsonPath:

```
Unexpected token '?': _$_v.b.d.e.f[?(_$_v.type=='in'
```

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
$.a[?@.b.d.e.f[?@.type == 'in']].b.c.*.id
```

***NOTE:** `.*` and `[*]` are equivalent.*

This will search for all elements in `$.a` which contain a `@.b.d.e.f` which contains `@.type == 'in'`, then it queries the result of that to get `.b.c.*.id`

The key is using nested queries.

- The outer query `@.b.d.e.f[?@.type == 'in']` acts on the elements of `a` and is an existence test: it doesn't have any comparisons.  If the test returns a non-empty result, then the element is selected.
- The inner query `@.type == 'in'` acts on the elements of `f` and checks for the condition that you want.

The final piece is simply navigating to the information you want (`.b.c.*.id`) from the elements of `a` that are returned.

---

This is compliant with the [pending IETF JSON Path specification](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-jsonpath-base-21.html), which can be tested in my playground https://json-everything.net/json-path.

Not all libraries will be compliant with the specification.  You'll need to check with the library you're using to see what's supported.

Comment: can this be modified to jayway json path?

Comment: $.a[?(@.b.d.e.f[?(@.type=='in')])].b.c[*].id
tried equivalent jway json path but not working ,can you please have a look?

Comment: That implementation hasn't yet updated to the new spec.  I'm not sure what it supports.  I would expect it to work though. The only thing that it might not support would be the nested query, which is essential to making this work.